# Detect if a process can't file a file

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

in windows, I use sysinternals' processpx to detect if a process tries to access a file that doesn't exist.
Is there a way to do this on osx?

Comment: Why the Linux tag? Consider `strace` or `dtruss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this relatively easily with a dtrace script.

We want to record all open calls for filename,
if the open fails, and the errno is ENOENT, then display the process name, pid and filename.

```
syscall::open*:entry
{ self->path = copyinstr(arg0); }

syscall::open*:return
/ arg0 < 0 && errno == ENOENT /
{ printf("%s(%d): %s", execname, pid, self->path); }
```

then `sudo dtrace -s <script>`.

On OSX, though, with system integrity protection, a lot of processes will not be monitored by this.